# Functional DropDown Menu With Only CSS & HTML?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to figure out how to program a drop down menu that actually can function, is compatible with my original programming (online ones disabled my previous code), and only appears if the mouse hovers over the page I want.

```
    <title>Handmade with Joy</title>

<style>


    .store-pics {
        display: inline-block;
    }

    @font-face {
        font-family: "Italianno";
        src: url("Italianno-Regular-OTF.otf") format("opentype");
    }

    body { 
        font-size: 200%; 
        font-family: "Italianno", serif;
        background-image: url("file:///E:/Grace/Art/Skin%20Care%20Products/background.jpg"); 
        color: #FF9ED5; 
        }

    ul#tabs { 
        list-style-type: none; 
        margin: 30px 0 0 0; 
        padding: 0 0 0.3em 0; 
    }

    ul#tabs li { 
        display: inline; 
    }

    ul li ul {
        padding: 0;
        position: absolute;
        display: none;
        opacity: o;
        visibility: hidden;
    }

    ul#tabs li a { 
        color: #FFE8F0; 
        background: rgb(255, 189, 220); 
        border: 1px solid rgb(255,255,255); 
        border-bottom: none; 
        padding: 0.3em; 
        text-decoration: none; 
    }

    ul#tabs li a:hover { 
        background-color: rgb(252, 151, 190);  
    }

    ul#tabs li a.selected { 
        color: rgb(255, 189, 220); 
        background: #FFE8F0;  
        font-weight: bold; 
    }

    div.tabContent.hide { 
        display: none; 
    }

    div {
        width:80vw; 
        margin: 0 auto;
    }  

    #title {
        color: #FF9ED5;
        text-align: center;
    }

    .about {
        position: relative;
    }

    .list {
        display: block;
        margin: 0 auto;
    }

    #about-title {
        position: absolute;
        left: 47%;
        margin-left: -50px;
        top: 550px;
        display: block;
        color: #FF9ED5;
        text-align: center;
        z-index: 2;
    }

    img.border-label {
        position: absolute;
        display: block;
        left: 40%;
        margin-left: -40px;
        top: 550px;
        width: 335px;
        height: 140px;
    }

    #natures-gifts {
        position: absolute;
        left: 44%;
        margin-left: -40px; 
        transform: rotate(-16deg);
        top: 550px;
    }

</style>

<script> 
    var tabLinks = new Array();
    var contentDivs = new Array();
    function init() {
        var tabListItems = document.getElementById('tabs').childNodes;
        for ( var i = 0; i < tabListItems.length; i++ ) {
            if ( tabListItems[i].nodeName == "LI" ) {
                var tabLink = getFirstChildWithTagName( tabListItems[i], 'A' );
                var id = getHash( tabLink.getAttribute('href') );
                tabLinks[id] = tabLink;
                contentDivs[id] = document.getElementById( id );
            }
        }

        var i = 0;

        for (var id in tabLinks) {
            tabLinks[id].onclick = showTab;
            tabLinks[id].onfocus = function() { this.blur() };
            if (i == 0) tabLinks[id].className = 'selected';
            i++;
        }

        var i = 0;

       for ( var id in contentDivs ) {
            if ( i != 0 ) contentDivs[id].className = 'tabContent hide';
            i++;
            }
        }

        function showTab() {
            var selectedId = getHash( this.getAttribute('href') );
                for ( var id in contentDivs ) {
                    if ( id == selectedId ) {
                        tabLinks[id].className = 'selected';
                        contentDivs[id].className = 'tabContent';
                    } else {
                        tabLinks[id].className = '';
                        contentDivs[id].className = 'tabContent hide';
                    }
                }
            return false;
        }

         function getFirstChildWithTagName( element, tagName ) {

            for ( var i = 0; i < element.childNodes.length; i++ ) {

                if ( element.childNodes[i].nodeName == tagName ) 
                    return element.childNodes[i];
                }
            }

        function getHash( url ) {
            var hashPos = url.lastIndexOf ( '#' );
            return url.substring( hashPos + 1 );
        }

    </script>
<body onload="init()">


<div class = "everything">
        <Img class = "flourish" src="file:///E:/Grace/Art/Clay/Manga%20Cute%20Bunny/Branches%20Finished.png" height = "100px"> 

<div class = "program">
    <h1 id="title">Handmade with Joy</h1>



<div class="list">    
    <ul id="tabs">
       <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>

      <li><a href="#store">Soap</a></li>

            <ul>
                <li><a href="#mp">Melt & Pour</a></li>

                <li><a href="#cp">Cold Process</a></li>

                <li><a href="#hp">Hot Process</a></li>

            </ul>

    </ul>




    <div class="tabContent" id="about">

        <IMG class="honey-milk-soap-cover" src="file:///E:/Grace/Art/Skin%20Care%20Products/M&P%20Soap
        %20Making/End%20Product/Honey%20&%20Milk/DSCN6735%20-%20Copy.JPG" width="550"> 

        <h2 class = small-tab-titles id="natures-gifts">Nature's Gifts</h2>
    </div>
    </div> 


    <div class="tabContent" id="store">

        <h2>Store</h2>

        <div>

        <div>
        </div>

    </div>



    <div class="tabContent" id="reaching-out">

        <h2>Reaching Out</h2>
            <br>  
        <div>

            <h3>Contacts Form:</h3>

        </div>

    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you reset your code to hide it whenever the preferred li being hovered with this code:

```
#tabs li:hover ul {
   display: inline;
   opacity: 1;
   visibility: visible;
   margin-top: 27px;
   margin-left: -42px;
}
```

I've made a [**demo here**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/QyEOoO) with your code

Comment: Thanks!  The drop down menu, however, disappeared when I tried to mouse over the drop down menu to click on. How would I do that?

Comment: Easy. change the margin-top of the submenu ul to margin-top: 27px; instead of 30px. I updated the answer

Answer (score 1):

If this is what you look for:

> only appears if the mouse hovers over the page

You may use this:

```
select#my_select{ display: none }
body:hover select#my_select{ display: block }
```